# Div with Onlick event inside another onclick div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger the onclick event to call the function "quickColorChange()" inside the parent div which has also an onlick event called "showColorChange()".

But if i trie , the showColorChange() function is called.

```html
<div class="card__image" id="changeStatusColor30013956" onclick="showColorChange('30013956','#dcdcdc'); return false;" data- emplrcd="1" data-id="30013956" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="width:52px!important;background:#dcdcdc"
  data-original- title="Status" aria-describedby="tooltip85683">
  <div style="cursor:pointer;height: 100%;width: 13px;position: 
    absolute;right: 0px;background: black;color: white;font-weight: bold;">
    <span style="position: absolute; top: 40%; right: 0; font-size: 20px;">&lt; 
    </span>
  </div>
  <div onclick="quickColorChange('rot');event.stopPropagation;" style="border-radius:50%;background- 
    color:#FE0000;width:32px;height:32px;margin-top: 12px;margin-left: 4px;">
  </div>
  <div onclick="quickColorChange('gelb');event.stopPropagation;" style="border-radius:50%;background- 
    color:#E69123;width:32px;height:32px;margin-top: 12px;margin-left: 4px;">
  </div>
  <div onclick="quickColorChange('grün');event.stopPropagation;" style="border-radius:50%;background- 
    color:#6EA046;width:32px;height:32px;margin-top: 9px;margin-left: 4px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: You forgot to end your quote on the first parent div. when you called the onClick function

Comment: What do you mean? There's a closing quote in `onclick="showColorChange('30013956','#dcdcdc'); return false;"`

Answer (score 0):

try by modifying 
`event.stopPropagation;`
with
`event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: No. Nothing happens

Comment: @user3625342 You have to put `()` after a function name to call the function.

Comment: @Barmar my function call looks now like this: onclick="quickColorChange('grün');event.stopPropagation();" But dosen't work

Comment: @legalizeSINCE88 It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ja5gxhcd/1/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22834896)

Comment: @FZs This does answer the question, although it probably would have been better as a comment and voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Put your parameters of the function:

```
showColorChange('30013956','#dcdcdc')
```

in the javascript instead.

Comment: Also I just noticed that he hasn't quoted the onClick function in his parent div correctly.He forgot to put surround it with quotes.